# Fast output of large text QT

Tags: qt, qt5

I am new in Qt and I need your advices. I make an application that outputs large text data to UI. I use QPlainTextEdit to output. For example, it outputs ~300'000 words during ~1800ms. At that time app freezes and doesn't respond to user. That's bad and I want app to stay active while outputing. I've tryed the way: outputing words in other thread using QThread, so main thread would be available and app wouldn't freeze. But it turned out that UI object can't be changed by not main thread. Please correct me if I am wrong. So I'm stuck on this problem. Should I use any tricks, if UI object really can't be changed by other thread?

Comment: Re. `"it outputs ~300'000 words during ~1800ms."` but *why*?  No human can read that amount of text in that time -- or even over the space of a few hours.  You should probably rethink things a bit.

Comment: What widget do you use? Does it need to be editable, does it display rich text. Do you append text word by word calling slot multiple times? Try reading/producing/recieving it from another thread and then pass it to gui thread over signal-slot mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. 1) My output widget should have a scroll bar. And user could come at any place of the output widget using it. I can add words to widget as it scrolls, but app probably would freeze if user would abruptly pull the scroll bar 2) I have ready-made std::vector of words. Now I try to use QPlainText but output widget is not principled. It can be QListWidget or any other